Adding rule in Power BI Deployment
I have to set a rule for a new report in Power BI deployment pipeline to use Production's database not PreProduction's. I have done it successfully for all the datasets except one (despite the databases are the same).
I keep having following error:

I have checked that all the necessary tables exist in both databases on both servers.
Microsoft support gives following explanation to the error, which dies not help either:

How to get rid of the error message and set deployment rule? (for the same servers and databases there was no issue in other datasets)

So the problem turned out to be because changing source button was blocked also in Power BI Desktop app.
Go to advanced query editor:

Check if 1st step for every data source's applied step is Source (personally for me it was not enough)
If button is still disabled, change data source manually by editing Source

